how to save multiple file upload in spring boot
I am working on a small ecommerce app with spring boot. At first I only give the user the privilege of picking one image when uploading a product which was working fine. Now I want to give them the opportunity to upload multiple images for each product upload. The condition is that a user should upload a minimum of 2 images and maximum of 5 images while uploading a product. That's where I am stocked because I need to pass the arrays of images with other product's details and also I need to wait for the upload of the images to complete before proceeding with the uploading of other product details so that I can take the images path and save it to my product table because I am not storing the images in my database but rather a path to the images. I also need to loop through the files uploaded so that I can know how many files that the user picked as well as saving their path to my image1,image2,...imageN.
This is what I did in the single upload, I am looking for a way to modify this to accept a multiple upload of product images
    @Data
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class ProductImageEntity {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid",strategy = "uuid2")
        private String id;
        private String fileType;
        private String fileName;
        @Lob
        @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
        private byte[] data;
    
        public ProductImageEntity(String fileType, String fileName, byte[] data) {
            this.fileType = fileType;
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    
    public interface ProductImageService {
    
        public ProductImageEntity saveProductImage (MultipartFile file) throws Exception;
        public ProductImageEntity getProductImage(String productId) throws Exception;
    }
    
    @Service
    public class ProductImageServiceImpl implements ProductImageService {
       private ProductImageRepository productImageRepository;
    
        public ProductImageServiceImpl(ProductImageRepository productImageRepository) {
            this.productImageRepository = productImageRepository;
        }
    
        @Override
        public ProductImageEntity saveProductImage(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
            String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    
            if (fileName.contains("..")) {
                throw new DataNotAcceptableException("File Name Contains invalid character");
            } else {
                ProductImageEntity productImageEntity = new ProductImageEntity(file.getContentType(), fileName, file.getBytes());
                return productImageRepository.save(productImageEntity);
            }
        }
    
            @Override
            public ProductImageEntity getProductImage(String productId) throws Exception {
                return productImageRepository.findById(productId)
                        .orElseThrow(()->new Exception("Product Image Id not found"));
            }
    }
    
    public interface ProductImageRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductImageEntity,String> {
    }
    
    //This is the method in the productServiceImpl that uploaded the product
    //It's where I want to modify to accomplish what I need
    
    @Override
        public ResponseEntity<CustomPaymentResponse> uploadProduct(UploadProductDto uploadProductDto, MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    
            SellerEntity seller = sellerRepository.findByEmail(uploadProductDto.getSellerEMail());
    
            if (Objects.isNull(seller)) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new CustomPaymentResponse(false, "Seller Email not found", null));
            }
            if (uploadProductDto.getPrice().intValue() <=0){
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new CustomPaymentResponse(false, "Invalid product price", null));
            }
            categoryName(uploadProductDto.getCategory());
    
            ProductImageEntity imageEntity = productImageService.saveProductImage(file);
            if (Objects.isNull(imageEntity)) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new CustomPaymentResponse(false, "The product image format not accepted", null));
            }
            //This retrieves the downloaded image path and store it to the variable downloadUrl
            //so that it can be saved as the productImage
            String downloadUrl = "download/" + imageEntity.getId();
            ProductEntity product = ProductEntity.builder()
                    .productImage(downloadUrl)
                    .productName(uploadProductDto.getProductName())
                    .brand(uploadProductDto.getBrand())
                    .category(uploadProductDto.getCategory())
                    .description(uploadProductDto.getDescription())
                    .productOwner(seller)
                    .price(uploadProductDto.getPrice())
                    .status("Pending Approval")
                    .paymentStatus(PaymentStatus.PENDING.name())
                    .uploadedDate(new Date())
                    .approvedOrRejectedDate(null)
                    .updatedDate(null)
                    .build();
            productRepository.save(product);
            return sellerPayStackService.initializePayment(product.getId());
        } 
    
    @RestController
    public class ProductController {
    
        private ProductService productService;
        private ProductImageService productImageService;
    
        public ProductController(ProductService productService, ProductImageService productImageService) {
            this.productService = productService;
            this.productImageService = productImageService;
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/product/upload")
        public ResponseEntity<CustomPaymentResponse> uploadProduct(@RequestParam("productImage")MultipartFile file,
                                                                   @RequestPart("product")UploadProductDto uploadProductDto, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
            return productService.uploadProduct(uploadProductDto,file,request);
        }
         //method to download the product image
        @GetMapping("/download/{productImageId}")
        public ResponseEntity<Resource>downloadProductImage(@PathVariable("productImageId")String productImageId) throws Exception {
            ProductImageEntity imageEntity = productImageService.getProductImage(productImageId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(imageEntity.getFileType()))
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"image; fileName=\""+imageEntity.getFileName()
                    +"\"")
                    .body(new ByteArrayResource(imageEntity.getData()));
        }
    }


i didn't quite understand what exactly you are having trouble with? And you haven't shown what you have tried (to upload multple images)? anyways simple google search delivered this as first result https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-upload-multiple-images-spring-boot-udara-san/

thanks for your response. I have solved it by passing a Set of my image entity to the product entity as one of the attributes. With that I can be able to upload multiple images for one product
